# I don´t understand this syntax

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I am not sure what object is referring code `.push(node)`. If it's referring to node or parent variable.

I have put `console.log()` to the code, but is being updated data and dataMap variable. I'm very confused.

```
// *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
// create a name: node map
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.name] = node;
    return map;
}, {});
// create the tree array
var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
    // add to parent
    var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
    if (parent) {
        // create child array if it doesn't exist
        (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
            // add node to child array
            .push(node);
    } else {
        // parent is null or missing
        treeData.push(node);
    }
});
```

I want to understand the code.

Comment: It's part of the previous line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// create child array if it doesn't exist
(parent.children || (parent.children = []))
// add node to child array
  .push(node);
```

is this:

```
(parent.children || (parent.children = [])).push(node);
```

which would be the same logic as

```
if (!parent.children) {
  parent.children = [];
}

parent.children.push(node);
```